# Visual Studio 2015 freezes after trying to exit the debug session of a C# project

Tags: visual-studio, debugging, visual-studio-2015, freeze

I'm having a strange problem for about two weeks with my visual studio installation.
I am on VS2015 Update 3 and Windows 10 1903 working with C# behind a proxy.

The problem? Every time I try to stop debugging, Visual Studio freezes. Sometimes a window from visual studio pops up that the process hangs and I can try to kill it (that does not always work). Sometimes this window is not shown at all. Most of the time I end up killing VS with Sysinternals ProcessExplorer - and I get the message that the process of my debugged project could not be killed (access denied, even as admin). I start VS again, trying to execute/debug my project - but that fails, since the process of the project is still alive and VS can't overwrite the executable. Cleaning the project helps sometimes, but other times I end up starting/restarting VS multiple times, killing processes with ProcessExplorer until I can start the next debug session and everything starts from the beginning.

What have I tried?

- Disabled .vshost Process
- Internet Explorer > Advanced Settings > Security > Certificate Stuff disabled
- Detaching the debugger first works in most cases
- Disabled my network card. This seems to work but is *not* really a solution
- Visual Studio repair installation
- Disabled all plugins/extensions/addons (LanceLi-MSFT)
- Cleared VS component cache (LanceLi-MSFT)
- Installed [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/mt752379(v=vs.140)) Patch (LanceLi-MSFT)

ideas and suggestions are welcome :)

Comment: does it have the same problem with other visual studio projects?

Comment: Maybe you can clean the cache of vs and restart vs, follow [this](https://github.com/Codealike/Codealike-KnowledgeBase/blob/master/clear-visual-studio-component-cache.md). And disable the third-party extensions to check if it helps. Hard to say, but several issues I met with strange behaviors result from the third-party vs extensions. And does this issue occur before in windows 1809?

Comment: @CarCar Tried some other projects... everything is fine. so i created a new project and added the source-code files to this new project and the problem returns... So the problem might be in my source code - either a coding problem or an extension that is unable to process those files...

Comment: @LanceLi-MSFT No, the 1903 update has been rolled out before. I added this information just for the case that there might be a known bug with vs2015 and w10 1903

Comment: @Michael Have you installed [this patch](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/mt752379(v=vs.140)) to fix some known issues for VS2015 update3? After that, go Tools=>Import and Export Settings to reset all vs settings. If the issue still persists after all above, this issue may be related to the code, it means we can't check it unless we can reproduce it :(

Comment: @LanceLi-MSFT The first debug session after installing the patch was good. But then the problem returned. Any ideas how to tackle this? The project is a really small prototype, which uses a BackgroundWorker to collects data from a database and writes the data to an excelsheet using epplus... nothing special :/

Comment: comment out some more complex code. something is not terminating correctly.... if the project isn't that complex then you might be able to methodically comment out until you find which is the culprit. once you have that.... post here and let us know and maybe something isn't being handled correctly with that bit of code.

Answer (score 0):

Use [Process Monitor](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/procmon) to observe the system calls Visual Studio (devenv.exe) makes. Look for file system calls that are doing lots of reads (e.g., on the Browse.VC.db file which is a symptom of [this issue currently under investigation](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/693475/frequent-hangs-between-2-and-5-seconds-long.html)).

Perhaps you'll see a read of a file that you can fix with a configuration change. If not and it looks like a bug, report a problem to microsoft using *Help > Send Feedback > Report a Problem...*.

[image: Report a Problem]